# QGIS and LRS. Define points along line from distance in .txt file

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing

I'm working with QGIS 2.14.3. and am a fairly novice user.

I have a shapefile layer with polylines, each line is identified by a unique 'LCS_CODE' field.
In a spreadsheet (imported as a text file layer) I have speed sign data which I want to display. There are three columns ('SPEED','LCS_CODE','DISTANCE'), the 'SPEED' of the sign, the 'LCS_CODE' it is on and the 'DISTANCE' from the start of the LCS_CODE it is located. There may be more than 1 speed sign per LCS_CODE. Other than the distance field there is no geographic info. 
I want to get QGIS to display the speed sign at the specified distance along the LCS_CODE line.

My first thought was to use LRS but I cannot get it to 'see' the text file layer to load it as the point layer. 
I then created a points layer with the same 3 fields (SPEED, LCS_CODE, DISTANCE) with the thought that I would copy/paste the spreadsheet data straight into the attribute table but cannot see a way to do this without artificially creating points for each row first.

How else might I achieve this, to me it sounds reasonably simple however it's obviously beyond me!!